# Websocket key not being received from header by PHP host

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I'm trying to implement websockets into my page, and it works great in the dev environment, but when I deploy to the other location, the php host doesn't receive the key needed for the handshake. (Sec-WebSocket-Key is *missing* from the header, even though it is being sent (I confirmed it was sent in the developer tools of chrome))

I am running a php websocket server, and the client is javascript.

To get the header sent by the client, I am doing the following:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);
socket_listen($socket);
```

and then once the user connects:

```
$socketNew = socket_accept($socket); //accept new socket
$header = socket_read($socketNew, 1024); //read data sent by the socket
```

Here is the header being sent now:

```
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ja;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Upgrade
Cookie:--long jumble of text--
Host:--hidden--:8080
Origin:--hidden--
Pragma:no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key:BuiFne7w8lCA5qt4ojEjgg==
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
```

and here is the header as received by the PHP host:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ---hidden---:8080
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: ---hidden---
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ja;q=0.6
Cookie:  ---really long jumble of text---
```

Comment: Where did you get the headers from? From the browser or somewhere else?

Comment: From the (php) socket host. I run socket_accept on the newly connected socket, and then socket_read to get the header. (then the connection fails, since the header is missing the key)

Comment: 1st rule of debugging: check data on the source first. "Here is the headers being sent" --- you cannot state that, you can only state that those are headers "being received". You still don't know what was sent.

Comment: how can I see the header before it is sent?

Comment: Not "before" but "where" it was sent. In the client browser.

Comment: oh, ok. I can see now that the key *is* being sent. I just need to find why it is not being received. I'll update my question now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116747/discussion-between-skeets-oreilly-and-zerkms).

Comment: @zerkms thanks for the help with investigating headers. It eventually lead me to find the problem -- which is actually in the last line of PHP code I posted in my question. I'll post the answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was rather frustrating and time consuming to solve, so hopefully this will help someone.

the 2nd parameter in socket_read is the *max length* to read from the headers. Why you wouldn't want all the headers is beyond me. I noticed in many basic tutorials of websockets that the second parameter was 1024, and I didn't think to check the docs to see what the number was for. Turns out, that number was just barely too low to work in my case. I just upped the number considerably so it won't be a problem in the future, and now it works great

so to be clear:

If this doesn't work:

```
$header = socket_read($socketNew, 1024); //read data sent by the socket
```

increase the max length to read:

```
$header = socket_read($socketNew, 5000); //read data sent by the socket
```

Once I changed the number here (and every other place with a max length param) it worked instantly.